# MongodbReactive what to do when you have empty result

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

In case no email was found in the database the findByEmail returns null, so it breaks all the process

```
public Mono<UserDto> findByEmail(String email) {
    return this.userRepository.findByEmail(email) // <---- ERROR HERE 
            .map(userEntity -> userMapper.toDto(userEntity)) // <---- ERROR HERE 
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty());
}

@Override
public Mono<String> authenticate(String accessToken) {
    return this.facebookService.verifyAccessToken(accessToken)
            .flatMap(userFacebookDto ->
                    this.findByEmail(userFacebookDto.getEmail()) 
                            .map(userDbDto -> {
                                String token = "";
                                if (isNull(userDbDto)) {
                                    UserEntity userEntity = this.userFacebookMapper.toEntity(userFacebookDto);
                                    this.userRepository.save(userEntity)
                                            .map(ue -> this.jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(ue));
                                } else {
                                    token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(this.userMapper.toEntity(null));
                                }
                                return token;
                            })
            );
}
```

What is on your opinion a good chaining strategy for this case in order to continue the execution of the rest of the code ?

The error :
"The mapper returned a null Mono"

Comment: please clarify: 
1. is email pass as a parameter to `findByEmail` is null? or, `userRepository.findByEmail(email)` returned null?
 2. one more question, what does `userRepository.findByEmail(email)` return when no `userEntity` is found?

Comment: The reactive mongo repository is not supposed to return null, so your problem likely lies somewhere else. To find the exact place you can enable debug mode. See: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#debug-activate

Comment: @MartinTarjányi what does mongo repository returns if he doesn't find something ?

Comment: @TaoufikJabbari it returns empty Mono.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi an empty mono isn't null ? if it goes to the next .map what does it get in the input ? a null ?  please explain how the findById will send a mono.empty and then the next .map or .flatMap what will he get in the parameter of the lamba inside it ?

Comment: Mono/Flux can not contain null value. When they are empty, subsequent map/flatMap/doOnNext/etc. operator lambdas are just simply skipped, not invoked.